# Where can I locate my Angular 2 CLI TypeScript error?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, type-conversion, angular-cli

So, I have just upgraded my Angular CLI project to the latest version.

Angular CLI is 1.0.0 now and @angular/common is 4.0.0

After compiling the previously working project (with `ng build`) I received dozens of errors, like this:

```
C:/tools/myproject/src/$$_gendir/app/modules/wp-components/wp-components.component.ngfactory.ts (1207,11): Type 'number | true' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

I might be able solve this type related error, but I don't know where to locate...

I guess `C:/tools/myproject/src/app/modules/wp-components/wp-components.component.ts` is the original of `C:/tools/myproject/src/$$_gendir/app/modules/wp-components/wp-components.component.ngfactory.ts` (which is listed in the error message).

**My question is:**

This file has 225 lines. What is this coordinate in the error message: `(1207,11)`

*If you have solution for this problem, it is welcomed as well. ;-)*

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: can you please post your code for that `wp-components`
This seems like an issue related to typescript upgrade not angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem when I upgraded Angular CLI.

**The problem:**

The source for it is logical, but I just didn't think about it.

In my case I had a typed custom Type parameter or variable as string or number, but I've used it in an if condition without an operator to check if it was empty or not.

*For example:*

```
export class ExampleType {
   id: number,
   title: string
}

if(!ExampleType.id) {
    // this will produce an error because ExampleType.id
    // is used as a boolean in this case
}
```

whereas using it like this will get rid of the error:

```
if(ExampleType.id < 1) {
    // this works
}
```

**Understanding the debugging message:**

As far as I can see the numbers don't make sense, but the file names seem to be the first occurance of one of the cases above. So if you get the error, just search this file for if/switch conditions that might use your parameter like above and change them to use the correct comparison operator and then look at the next filename that appears after running it again.
Notice: you have to check the component.ts and also the component.html file, as it also affects ngIfs in the template file.

**Tip on finding the faulty attributes:**

The debug message doesn't give any information which attribute is the error source. My solution was to just change every attribute in my custom Type to "any" and then change it back one by one to see where the error started coming back again.
(maybe that helps)